# How to generate group based columns faster?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create a column for my dataframe that is based on anther column. For example, I have a dataframe like this:

```
      Content        Date
ID                       
Bob  birthday  2010.03.01
Bob    school  2010.04.01
Tom  shopping  2010.02.01
Tom      work  2010.09.01
Tom   holiday  2010.10.01
```

I want to generate a column that equals to the size of the `ID`, so the resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
      Content        Date  Size
ID                       
Bob  birthday  2010.03.01     2
Bob    school  2010.04.01     2
Tom  shopping  2010.02.01     3
Tom      work  2010.09.01     3 
Tom   holiday  2010.10.01     3
```

The standard way seems to use `groupby` and `transform`. The code will do the work:

```
df['Size'] = df['Date'].groupby(df.index).transform(np.size)
```

The problem is, `transform` works really slow. In a dataframe with about `40k` rows, the above code takes more than `10 sec` on my PC. I regularly work on datasets that are larger than 1 million rows and generating group-based variables is a frequent practice.

The problem lies with `transform`. For example, if I generate `cumcount` on the same dataframe using

```
# method 1: use groupby attribute 'cumcount'
df['cumcount'] = df['Date'].groupby(df.index).cumcount()
# method 2: use 'transform'
df['cumcount'] = df['Date'].groupby(df.index).transform(lambda x: np.arange(0, len(x)))
```

`method 1` takes about `0.2 sec` while `method 2` again takes about `14 sec`. However, `groupby` does not seem to have attributes for generating columns like `group size, group max, group mean`, etc. Is there another method that can improve the performance here?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about `df['cumcount'] = df['Date'].groupby(df.index).transform('count')` how does this perform?

Comment: @EdChum, thanks. I just tested it. It takes about `11 sec`, similar to `tranform(np.size)`. I think the problem lies with `transform`, not the function it calls.

Comment: I just did a `%timeit` on your sample data and saw the same

Comment: Are you trying to perform multiple aggregate functions on your groupby? You can pass a list of function names: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once

Comment: @EdChum, no I am trying to generate a column that contains the statistics, which is exactly what `transform` in the documentation does: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation, except I am not happy with the speed. This can be done really fast in STATA, I would believe python can do it well too.

Comment: implement the method described here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6496.

These are equivalent, but 2nd is faster

```
In [41]: %timeit grp.transform(np.size)
1 loops, best of 3: 442 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit pd.concat([ Series([r]*len(grp.groups[i])) for i, r in enumerate(grp.size().values) ],ignore_index=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 135 ms per loop
```

This scales with the number of groups not the number of rows

Waiting on someone to implement. Its not difficult, and would be a good first pull-request.

Comment: thanks! That final result in the linked page `pd.Series(np.repeat(grp.mean().values, grp.count().values))` works great. In fact, using grp.size().values can improve the speed further (more than halved the time in my test).

Comment: In fact, in my example (generating group size column), using `group.count().values` (twice here) takes 4 sec, while using `group.size().values` takes 0.07 sec. Maybe you can add this point to that thread of discussion?

Comment: currently an open issue about count/size in that count should be a synonym for size

Comment: yeah but there seems to be a considerable speed advantage of size over count.